# How to get rid of “media playing” notification by Chrome on Android?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, browser, notifications

My HTML5 game has some background music that uses Howler.js in "html5" mode, which apparently triggers Chrome for Android's media playback notifications. This means a notification appears while the user has my game open in any tab:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS0fB.png)